# Getting last word in a string on Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

A similar question has already been asked, however Amazon Redshift does not support some of the commands of MySQL, so there is a need to adapt the code.

I am trying to extract the last word out of a string in a given column.

```
col1 |
+-----+
|a    |
|b c  |
|d e f|
```

This would be an output:

```
|result|
+------+
|a     |
|c     |
|f     |
```

I have tried working with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX("a b c", " ", -1);
```

however it does not work with Redshift.

Thus, I thought about using `SUBSTRING` with `POSITION`, but `POSITION` finds only the first space and does not seem to work:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, POSITION (' ' in REVERSE(column)), 10)
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the string, take the first word then reverse it back like this

```
select reverse(split_part(reverse('ab bc cd'),' ',1));
```

Comment: works like a charm (at least in a clean data), thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for this :) had been scratching my head to find this for some time now.

Comment: Thank you! In case anyone needs to remove the last word of a string, use the following `select trim(replace('ab bc cd', reverse(split_part(reverse('ab bc cd'),' ',1)), ''));`

Answer (score 1):

use split_part

```
select split_part(column,' ',len(column)-1)
```

Comment: It returns space, I think it would be necessary to specify the len part